# Selenium finds the element (anchor) but still says element not visible?

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait, linktext

I have a "clear all" button which is an anchor. The HTML structure is like this:

```
<div class="form-row toggle-closed" id="ProductFilters" style="display: block;">
    <div class="form-row__filter">
        <ul class="form-row__filter__bg-display">
            <li class="filter__group__item__small">
                <a id="ProductFiltersFilterText" class="f-right" data-select-all="ProductFilters" href="#">clear all</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Then in the Selenium test I'm trying to find the `a` tag using this:

```
SeleniumHelper.ExpandFilterSection(_webDriver, "#ProductFilters");
var clearAllButton = _webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.form-row__filter>ul>li>#ProductFiltersFilterText"));
clearAllButton.Click();
```

THen I started debugging, in the automated Chrome window I could see that by executing `ExpandFilterSection`, the filter was expanded, the "clear all" button was exposed, then a bug said:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: 'element not visible'
```

How ever in the Autos I see:
[image]

It seems that the "clear all" button is found, why does it say "element not visible"? Functionality of the button is trigger by JavaScript though.

Comment: Try scrolling to element before clicking on it.

Comment: @supputuri what does it mean by "scrolling to element"?

Comment: `var element = driver.FindElement(By.id("ProductFilters"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.MoveToElement(element);
actions.Perform();` this should bring the element to visible area.

Comment: why aren't you selecting the element by id?

Comment: @supputuri the code gave me errors, can you post an answer to explain your comment?

Comment: ((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(false);", element);

Comment: @DMart tried to use id, could see the same element in the Auto but same error happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `click()` on the element with text as **clear all** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `ElementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `linkText`:

  ```
  SeleniumHelper.ExpandFilterSection(_webDriver, "#ProductFilters");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.LinkText("clear all"))).Click();
  ```
- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  SeleniumHelper.ExpandFilterSection(_webDriver, "#ProductFilters");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("div#ProductFilters>div.form-row__filter>ul.form-row__filter__bg-display>li.filter__group__item__small>a#ProductFiltersFilterText"))).Click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  SeleniumHelper.ExpandFilterSection(_webDriver, "#ProductFilters");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[@id='ProductFilters']/div[@class='form-row__filter']/ul[@class='form-row__filter__bg-display']/li[@class='filter__group__item__small']/a[@id='ProductFiltersFilterText']"))).Click();
  ```