# How to determine if scrolling to the element is actually necessary?

Tags: .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I run multiple E2E scenarios, in one of the scenarios scrolling appeared to the element to be only solution to dependably click given link. However, that introduced 200% time execution increase, because driver tries to scroll for each element, as I would like to have universal method for clicking links with given text would like to avoid unnecessary scrolling.

Is there a method to determine if element is displayed in the viewport and one doesn't need to scroll to it?

Answer (score 2):

The preconditions for clickable `IWebElement` are `Displayed` and `Enabled`

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(...);
if (!(element.Displayed && element.Enabled))
{
    //scroll to the element
}
element.Click();
```

*You can probably drop the `element.Enabled` check, it will return false only if the element is [explicitly disabled](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_Enabled.htm). If you can click it after the scroll, it's enabled.

> The Enabled property will generally return true for everything except
>   explicitly disabled input elements.

Answer (score 0):

A bit unclear in which circumstances you have concluded *scrolling appeared to the element to be only solution to dependably click given link*. Ideally, if your usecase is to invoke `click()` on the element, ideally you need to use the *ExpectedConditions* as `element_to_be_clickable()` as follows:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("element_css"))).Click();
```

You can find a couple of detailed discussions in:

- [Selenium finds the element (anchor) but still says element not visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57957721/selenium-finds-the-element-anchor-but-still-says-element-not-visible/57958450#57958450)
- [ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible returns TimeoutException even when element is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50853798/expectedconditions-elementisvisible-returns-timeoutexception-even-when-element-i/50855181#50855181)

---

If *scrolling* appeares mandatory, to scroll an element within the **Viewport** before invoking `click()` you can also use the [Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) method.

You can find a detailed discussion in:
- [What is the difference between the different scroll options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54681172/what-is-the-difference-between-the-different-scroll-options/54689339#54689339)

---

At this point it is worth to mention, the following methods:

- [`MoveToElement()`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Interactions_Actions_MoveToElement.htm) from [Actions](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Interactions_Actions.htm) Class
- [`ElementToBeClickable()`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementToBeClickable.htm) from [ExpectedConditions](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm) Class

will automatically **scroll** the element within the *Viewport*.

You can find a detailed discussion in:

- [How to scroll a webpage using selenium webdriver in Python without using javascript method execute_script()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55361795/how-to-scroll-a-webpage-using-selenium-webdriver-in-python-without-using-javascr/55587059#55587059)